# What does the notation $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}$ mean?

Tags: notation

I am having trouble understanding the following notation. For example $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Does this mean $x$ is a vector of $d$ real numbers and $y$ is a real number? What does the $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean?

Similarly, does $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}$ mean $x$ is a vector of $d$ real numbers and $y$ is a real number?

Comment: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/),which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Correct**

If we write $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}$ then $x$ is a vector of $d$ real numbers and $y$ is a real number.

$f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is just a function that takes one $d$-vector and one number and spits out a real number.

The domain is a copy of $\mathbb R^{d+1}$ of course. It is probably written $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R} $ to simplify the notation later on.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. This follows logically to the paper. I will wait for others responses before accepting due to the downvotes.

Comment: @user16573587 Some people downvote the answers to question they downvote.